# Should we include the prepended year in the [us2012abcdefg] tag structure?

Tags: discussion, tags

Some tags currently have it, and some do not:

[image]

Let's standardize this. Additionally, we should decide whether or not to include the "A1" (which means that this is a patent's first filing) at the end of the patent number.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This site is interested in both issued patents and patent applications.  The designations for them differ.

For a patent **application**, use the prepended year as shown on the PTO website http://appft.uspto.gov/netahtml/PTO/srchnum.html :

> Example: Utility  : 20010000044

For an **issued** patent the options vary, but the form we are most interested in is a 7-digit number as shown at http://patft.uspto.gov/netahtml/PTO/srchnum.htm :

> All patent numbers must be seven characters in length, excluding
>   commas, which are optional. Examples: Utility --  5,146,634 6923014
>   0000001

The tags we use should follow these patterns.  They could perhaps become links to PTO source materials.

Comment: What happens when a patent gets issued, but has previously been discussed here?

Answer (score 1):

I agree that we should use the patterns used by the USPTO. Additionally, each tag really should have a tag wiki briefly summarizing what the patent or patent application is for, as well as a link to the full text of the patent.